# Display all possible matches with count in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as shown below

| Id | FName | Gender | StatusValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sam | Male | SV001 |
| 2 | Emma | Female | SV002 |
| 3 | Ava | Unknown |  |
| 4 | John | Male |  |
| 5 | Olivia | Female |  |
| 6 | Joe | Male |  |
| 7 | Mia | Female |  |

I want to display the below output

| Id | Gender | StatusValue | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Female | SV001 | 0 |
| 2 | Female | SV002 | 1 |
| 3 | Female | Empty | 2 |
| 4 | Male | SV001 | 1 |
| 5 | Male | SV002 | 0 |
| 6 | Male | Empty | 2 |
| 7 | Unknown | SV001 | 0 |
| 8 | Unknown | SV002 | 0 |
| 9 | Unknown | Empty | 1 |

Here I want to display all possible combinations with matching counts.
**Note**: cannot use common table expressions and PIVOT, since the tool is not supporting few of the SQL keywords.
I have tried the below but it is giving wrong count

```
SELECT Gender,StatusValue,Count(*) as Count FROM Persons 
WHERE Gender <> '' AND StatusValue <> '' 
GROUP BY Gender,StatusValue 
UNION
SELECT 
CASE WHEN G.Gender <> '' THEN G.Gender ELSE 'Empty' END,
CASE WHEN T.StatusValue <> '' THEN T.StatusValue ELSE 'Empty' END, 0 as COUNT from
(SELECT DISTINCT Gender FROM Persons) as G, (SELECT DISTINCT StatusValue FROM Persons) as T
```

Comment: Can you use `ROW_NUMBER()` to generate the `Id` of the combination?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select x.gender, y.status_value, count(id)
from (select distinct gender from t) x
cross join (select distinct status_value from t) y
left join t on (t.gender = x.gender or coalesce(t.gender, x.gender) is null)
  and (t.status_value = y.status_value or coalesce(t.status_value, y.status_value) is null)
group by x.gender, y.status_value
order by x.gender, y.status_value
```

Result:

```
 gender   status_value  (No column name) 
 -------- ------------- ---------------- 
 Female   null          2                
 Female   SV001         0                
 Female   SV002         1                
 Male     null          2                
 Male     SV001         1                
 Male     SV002         0                
 Unknown  null          1                
 Unknown  SV001         0                
 Unknown  SV002         0
```

The `left join` predicate is unnecessarily long due to the lack of the `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` operator in SQL Server. Apparently it's being implemented in SQL Server 2022, though.

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kPz6vZmr).

**Note**: The restriction not to use CTEs or pivot is somewhat artificial since SQL Server does support them.

Comment: MS SQL Server does support CTEs and `PIVOT`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Yes, not sure why the tool is designed like that and throwing error like PIVOT is unsupported keyword.

Answer (score 0):

[Working Fiddle Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/kwN37v47),

Assuming,

```
CREATE TABLE [X]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [FName] VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    [Gender] VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    [StatusValue] VARCHAR(10) NULL
);
```

This works,

```
;WITH S AS
(
  SELECT 'ZZZZZZZZ' [Sub]
),
G AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT [Gender] FROM [X]
),
SV AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT [StatusValue] FROM [X]
),
C AS
(
  SELECT
      G.[Gender],
      ISNULL(SV.[StatusValue], S.[Sub]) [StatusValue]
  FROM
      G
    CROSS JOIN
      SV
    CROSS JOIN
      S
),
D AS
(
  SELECT
    X.[Gender],
    ISNULL(X.[StatusValue], S.[Sub]) [StatusValue]
  FROM
    X
   CROSS JOIN
    S
),
A AS
(
  SELECT
      COUNT(*) [Count],
      D.[Gender],
      D.[StatusValue]
    FROM
      D
    GROUP BY
      D.[Gender],
      D.[StatusValue]
)
SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY C.[Gender], C.[StatusValue]) [Id],
        C.[Gender],
        CASE
            WHEN C.[StatusValue] = S.[Sub]
               THEN 'Empty'
            ELSE
               C.[StatusValue]
        END [StatusValue],
        ISNULL(A.[Count], 0) [Count]
   FROM
        C
     LEFT JOIN
        A
          ON A.[Gender] = C.[Gender] AND A.[StatusValue] = C.[StatusValue]
     CROSS JOIN
        S;
```

---

Or, [Without CTEs](https://dbfiddle.uk/O2Xmab02),

```
SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY C.[Gender], C.[StatusValue]) [Id],
        C.[Gender],
        CASE
            WHEN C.[StatusValue] = 'ZZZZZZZZZZ'
               THEN 'Empty'
            ELSE
               C.[StatusValue]
        END [StatusValue],
        COALESCE(A.[Count], 0) [Count]
   FROM
        (
        SELECT
                G.[Gender],
                COALESCE(SV.[StatusValue], 'ZZZZZZZZZZ') [StatusValue]
            FROM
                (SELECT DISTINCT [Gender] FROM [X]) G
              CROSS JOIN
                (SELECT DISTINCT [StatusValue] FROM [X]) SV
        ) C
     LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                COUNT(*) [Count],
                D.[Gender],
                D.[StatusValue]
              FROM
                (
                SELECT
                    X.[Gender],
                    COALESCE(X.[StatusValue], 'ZZZZZZZZZZ') [StatusValue]
                 FROM
                    X
                ) D
              GROUP BY
                D.[Gender],
                D.[StatusValue]
        ) A
          ON A.[Gender] = C.[Gender] AND A.[StatusValue] = C.[StatusValue];
```

Both produce

| Id | Gender | StatusValue | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Female | SV001 | 0 |
| 2 | Female | SV002 | 1 |
| 3 | Female | Empty | 2 |
| 4 | Male | SV001 | 1 |
| 5 | Male | SV002 | 0 |
| 6 | Male | Empty | 2 |
| 7 | Unknown | SV001 | 0 |
| 8 | Unknown | SV002 | 0 |
| 9 | Unknown | Empty | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

You can do one subquery to get all distinct combinations, and another to do your counting. In the end just LEFT JOIN two for desired results:

```
SELECT Cmb.Gender, Cmb.StatusValue, COALESCE(Cnt.Count, 0) AS Count
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    CASE WHEN G.Gender <> '' THEN G.Gender ELSE 'Empty' END AS Gender
  , CASE WHEN T.StatusValue <> '' THEN T.StatusValue ELSE 'Empty' END AS StatusValue
  FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT Gender FROM Persons) as G 
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT StatusValue FROM Persons) as T
) AS Cmb  -- cominations
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT 
   CASE WHEN Gender <> '' THEN Gender ELSE 'Empty' END AS Gender
  ,CASE WHEN StatusValue <> '' THEN StatusValue ELSE 'Empty' END AS StatusValue, Count(*) as Count 
  FROM Persons 
  GROUP BY CASE WHEN Gender <> '' THEN Gender ELSE 'Empty' END, CASE WHEN StatusValue <> '' THEN StatusValue ELSE 'Empty' END 
) AS Cnt -- counts
ON Cmb.Gender = Cnt.Gender AND Cmb.StatusValue = Cnt.StatusValue
```